# Quisiera extraer sólo una parte de un dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buen día a todos, quiero extraer sólo una parte de un dataset aquí tengo un parte del código:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_people

#Imágenes que contienen rosotros 
faces = fetch_lfw_people()
positiveImages = faces.images
```

En este caso me retorna (13233, 62, 47) que en total son 13,233 imágenes pero yo sólo quiero obtener una parte de este dataset por ejemplo extraer una parte y me diera (10000, 62, 47), gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola a todos encontré la manera sencilla de hacerlo:

```
foo = positiveImages[:10000, :, :]

In [1]: foo.shape
Out [1]: (10000, 62, 47)
```

Saludos